# CSS navigation issue

Tags: css, background, html-lists, divider

[image]

I need this divider (background) only for parent li-s, nothing else.

But getting in all child li's.

http://jsfiddle.net/rx8Mj/5 Hover on `projects` menu. You'll see what I'm talking about.

Answer (score 1):

```
.sf-menu > li a{ background: image}
```

to

```
.sf-menu > li > a{ background: image}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rx8Mj/6/